# replacement with sed linux

Tags: linux, shell

I need to perform a replacement with `sed` in linux but it doesn't work.

from `[$sonarqubeName]` to `[$projectName][$branchName]`

I tried `sed -i 's/[$projectName]/[$projectName][$branchName]/g'`

`sed -i 's/[$projectName]/[$projectName][$branchName]/g'`

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question. I'm not sure what you're attempting to accomplish :/

Comment: basically I need to make a replacement from [$sonarqubeName]

to [$projectName][$branchName]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `[`, `$`, `]` have special meaning inside the regular expressions (and some other characters as well, but they are not appearing in your search string). To use them as literal symbols you need to escape them with a backslash in the search expression. Try

```
sed -i 's/\[\$sonarqubeName\]/[$projectName][$branchName]/g'
```